# Do singletons have advantages over modules in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, design-patterns

I've used node/JavaScript for a few years and am now just getting familiar with TypeScript. I'm trying to wrap my head around when to use a class and when to use a module in TypeScript.

In JavaScript, I would often create modules like this:

```js
const name = "batman";

function getName() {
  return name;
}

module.exports = {
  name
};
```

In TypeScript this same code can be written as:

```js
const name: string = "batman";

export function getName(): string {
  return name;
}
```

However, in reading online, there are a fair amount of examples of singletons in TypeScript. I could also write this code as a singleton class like this:

```js
export default class Singleton {
    private static instance: Singleton;
    private name: string = "batman";

    private constructor() { }

    public static getInstance(): Singleton {
        if (!Singleton.instance) {
            Singleton.instance = new Singleton();
        }

        return Singleton.instance;
    }

    public getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

I'm struggling to see why I would ever create a singleton as the module is less code and arguably simpler. It also only exists as a single instance. Are there benefits that the singleton offers?

Comment: One of the benefits of traditional classes is that each instance can have it's own version of variables.  They can be independent of each other.  If you do not need that, using a singleton can keep you from having multiple instances of the class in memory all with the same values.

Comment: That makes sense. But you can do the same thing with a module and you also don't have to ever call getInstance(). It seems like modules result in cleaner code.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Module usage doesn't guarentee that you have an instance of a class.  A module could be a class definition that you later then have to make an instance of.

Comment: I mean the way I defined a module in the example. I'm not sure what a better name is. Technically in typescript a module could export multiple classes. However, the way I defined a module, there could only be one instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a module is much simpler and in many cases the better choice. However, singletons have two advantages:

- they can use lazy initialisation, when being instantiated on first use
- they can more easily be converted to a normal `class`, should the need for multiple instances arise. (And that's the case actually quite often, if your instance is stateful - unlike the code in your example).

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.